# Retaining the same xml structure for XSL-FO

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I have the following `XML` structure:

```
 <xml>
   <node level="1" companyname="A">
      <node level="2" companyname="b"></node>
  </node>
  <node level="1" companyname="c"> 
 </node>
```

I need to apply `XSL-FO` transformation, to get the output in pdf. However I need to preserve the format of the `XML` data. Please advise me on how this can be done.

This is the desired output:

> - A
>
>   - B
> - C

Answer (score 1):

If *"I need to preserve the format of the XML data."* means that you need to preserve the hierarchy, then you should be able to use a basic list.

This very basic example should get you started...

**XML Input** (modified to be well-formed)

```
<xml>
    <node level="1" companyname="A">
        <node level="2" companyname="b"/>
    </node>
    <node level="1" companyname="c"/>
</xml>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/xml">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page" page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in">
                    <fo:region-body margin="1in" margin-top="1.5in" margin-bottom="1.5in"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <fo:list-block>
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    </fo:list-block>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node">
        <fo:list-item>
            <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
                <fo:block>&#x2022;</fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-label>           
            <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
                <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="translate(@companyname,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')"/></fo:block>
                <xsl:if test="node">
                    <fo:list-block>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="node"/>
                    </fo:list-block>
                </xsl:if>
            </fo:list-item-body>
        </fo:list-item>     
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSL-FO Output**

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page" page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in">
         <fo:region-body margin="1in" margin-top="1.5in" margin-bottom="1.5in"/>
      </fo:simple-page-master>
   </fo:layout-master-set>
   <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
         <fo:list-block>
            <fo:list-item>
               <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
                  <fo:block>•</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-label>
               <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
                  <fo:block>A</fo:block>
                  <fo:list-block>
                     <fo:list-item>
                        <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
                           <fo:block>•</fo:block>
                        </fo:list-item-label>
                        <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
                           <fo:block>B</fo:block>
                        </fo:list-item-body>
                     </fo:list-item>
                  </fo:list-block>
               </fo:list-item-body>
            </fo:list-item>
            <fo:list-item>
               <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
                  <fo:block>•</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-label>
               <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
                  <fo:block>C</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-body>
            </fo:list-item>
         </fo:list-block>
      </fo:flow>
   </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

**PDF Output** (I used XEP, but FOP should yield the same results)

[image: so_fo-pdf.png]

Also, I'm not sure if it was a typo but `b` and `c` were lowercase in your input and uppercase in your output. If you don't have to force case, you can remove the `translate()`. Also, if you can use XSLT 2.0 you can use `upper-case()` instead of `translate()`.

Comment: this is what i was looking for. thanks a lot. Case was a typo. I am ok either way.